# Memory Leaks and Reference Counting in Python/C API

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-module, python-c-api, reference-counting

I am pretty new to Python and its C API. I still do not understand how reference counting works. I have written a module for particle tracking that exposes to python a number of C++ thread tracking functions that I had written and tested in the past. (I far as I can tell they do not have memory leaks themselves).

When I call one of these function from within Python repeatedly I can see that the memory usage is growing slowly. I believe there is a memory leak somewhere (probably everywhere :O)
I copied below the relevant fragment of the main tracking function so that someone could point to me whether I should make calls to Py_DECREFs (on item_py, for example?)

```
PyObject* _track_particles() {

        // more code here ... (no Python/C API  calls) 

        PyObject* result_py = PyTuple_New(particles.size());
        for(int i=0; i<particles.size(); ++i) {
            PyObject* item_py = PyTuple_New(2);
            if (lost_at_turn_idx[i] == PARTICLE_NOT_LOST) {
                int offset = i * (nr_turns+1) * 6 + nr_turns * 6;
                PyTuple_SetItem(item_py, 0, Py_True);
                PyTuple_SetItem(item_py, 1, Py_BuildValue("(dddddd)", 
                            data_out[offset + rx], data_out[offset + px],   
                            data_out[offset + ry], data_out[offset + py],
                            data_out[offset + de], data_out[offset + dl]));
            } else {
                PyTuple_SetItem(item_py, 0, Py_False);
                PyTuple_SetItem(item_py, 1, 
                        Py_BuildValue("(ii)", lost_at_turn_idx[i], 
                                              lost_at_element_idx[i]));
            }
            PyTuple_SetItem(result_py, i, item_py);
        }       
        return result_py;
    }
```

ps: found [this reference](http://edcjones.tripod.com/refcount.html) usefull

Comment: `(probably everywhere :O)` lol

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/extending.html#how-do-i-use-py-buildvalue-to-create-a-tuple-of-arbitrary-length) relevant?

> Use `t = PyTuple_New(n)` instead, and fill it with objects using `PyTuple_SetItem(t, i, o)` – note that this "eats" a reference count of `o`, so you have to `Py_INCREF()` it.

I'm not entirely sure whether this passage is clear, but it may be a good starting point.

Comment: But I am using PyTuple_New already. I am sorry, I did not understand your suggestion...

Comment: I didn't make a suggestion. I quoted the Python FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Many thanks to @DavidW for pointing this out to me (see comments). You [definitely need to `Py_INCREF` `Py_True` and `Py_False`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html). C does weird stuff when you do stuff you're not supposed to do, but it's hard to say if this might be causing your memory issues.

Several years late, but honestly, your code seems  <s>fine</s> . `result_py` is being returned and thus only needs to be `Py_DECREF`'d by the caller of `_track_particles` (I assume there is a caller for `_track_particles` within your C++ code since there is `PyObject *self`, `PyObject *args` defined in its signature) while `item_py` references are being stolen with `PyTuple_SetItem`. The rest of your new references are being stolen by `PyTuple_SetItem` so that's not a problem either. Interestingly, you have given a code fragment where not a single `Py_DECREF` is needed.

How are you checking for your memory leak? I know this is old, but Python 3 comes with [tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) so you could wrap a function call with that to check.

Comment: `PyTuple_SetItem(item_py, 0, Py_True);` is definitely not fine. It's adding `Py_True` to a tuple without incrementing it, so it'll end with `Py_True` being deallocated. It's not a memory leak though.

Comment: Oof, good catch. Yeah, for those special `Py_True`, `Py_False`, `Py_None` guys `Py_INCREF` is needed. I'll mention that in an edit. Thanks!